# Show that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and nonempty, then it does not have measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and nonempty, then it does not have measure zero.

**Attempt**: Let $U \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U \neq \emptyset$, then $\exists x \in U, r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$. Since $\mu(U) \geq \mu(B(x,r) > 0$, $U$ does not have measure zero.

That's the basic idea, but I am not sure how to make my argument stronger. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's exactly what you should do. Lebesgue measure is monotone, meaning $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$ when $A\subseteq B$,

Comment: Idea is OK: but (i) open sets of $\Bbb R^n$ are subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ not elements of $\Bbb R$. (ii) there's no reason to change the case of $U$. (iii) I'd prefer $\mu(U)\ge\mu(B(x,r))>0$ (using $\mu$ for the measure).

Comment: Presumable you are using the Lebesgue measure and you have $\mu B(x,r) > 0$.